# how to get multiple document with mongodb using node js and display into html page

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, mongodb

I have done , fetch data from mongodb and display it on html page using node js .

Problem is it only display one document while using findOne. and when I am using find . it doesn't display any data .

what i need to change in my html file please suggest me .

my **server.js** file is

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server;

app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server("localhost", 27017));
var db = mongoclient.db('prisync');

app.get('/', function(req, res){

// Find one document in our collection
db.collection('urlinfo').find().toArray(function(err, docs) {

    if(err) throw err;



    res.render('hello', docs);
});
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.send('Page Not Found', 404);
});



mongoclient.open(function(err, mongoclient) {

    if(err) throw err;

    app.listen(8080);
    console.log('Express server started on port 8080');
});
```

and My html file is

**hello.html**

```
 <body>

        <nav>
<ul>
<li>
  <a href="#" class="button add">Add Product</a>
  <div class="dialog" style="display:none">
  <div class="title">Add Product</div>
  <form action="/search" method="get">
    <input id = "name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Product Name"/>
    <input name="code" type="text" placeholder="Product Code"/>
    <input name="category" type="text" placeholder=" Category"/>
    <input name="brand" type="text" placeholder="Brand"/>
<input type="submit" value="Ok"/>
  </form>
</div>
</li>
<li class="radio">
  <a href="#" class="button active"></a>

  <a href="#" class="button"></a>

  <a href="#" class="button"></a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>        
</nav>

    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>


<h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
<h1>Hello, {{code}}!</h1>
<h1>Hello, {{category}}!</h1>


  </body>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for when you are calling the `find()` method?

Comment: your display logic:

<h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>
<h1>Hello, {{code}}!</h1>
<h1>Hello, {{category}}!</h1>

will not work for find query result because find query returns array of elements (no matter what is the count of results is) whereas findOne() returns single document. 

As solution to your problem, you can debug in two steps. 1- write console.log to display results in you find query success. 2- if results is coming then, iterate over result in your display logic and display results. As per my understanding find() query should be working fine, only problem is with display logic.

Comment: @chridam I changed find() instead of findOne()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this..

```
db.collection('urlinfo').find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
   if(err) throw err;
    res.render('hello', {'docs':docs});
   });
});
```

now hello.ejs, use the below code:

```
<% for (var d=0;d<docs.length;d++){%>
 <h1><%= docs[d].name %></h1>
 <h1>Hello, <%= docs[d].code} %></h1>
<h1>Hello, <%=docs[d].category %></h1> 
 <% } %>
```

This might be work.

Comment: Is i need to change hello.html to hello.ejs

Comment: Yes..,  If you are using expressJS then set your engine to ejs.

Comment: and i need to change hello.ejs ?

Comment: now its giving an error on   res.render('hello', {docs:docs});      the error is :    SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in /home/shubham/Music/prisync_0_2/views/hello.ejs while compiling ejs
   at Object.Function (<anonymous>)

Comment: in your server.js file use app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); instead of app.set('view engine', 'html'); and app.engine('html', cons.swig); remove this one. agian if error is came clearly mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you are using findOne,it gives one docs object only,but when you are using find method,it gives you list of docs object. you should use ng-repeat to iterate over list like

```
    <span ng-repeat="doc in docs">

     <h1>Hello, {{doc.name}}!</h1>
    <h1>Hello, {{doc.code}}!</h1>
    <h1>Hello, {{doc.category}}!</h1> 
</span>
```

Comment: This is not displaying any thing just display Hello

Comment: are you using angularjs for client end ?

Comment: before your answer not , but now i add the script that need for angular js . Is any thing more requirement for Angular js ?